# PowerShell append objects to variable list

Tags: powershell, variables, append

Fairly new to PowerShell and wanting to learn how to append objects to a variable list. Below is the error message:

```
Method invocation failed because [System.IO.FileInfo] does not contain a method named 'op_Addition'.
At C:\Users\Username\Desktop\Sandbox\New folder\BoxProjectFiles.ps1:117 char:4
+             $MechDWGFile += $file
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (op_Addition:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound
```

and code:

```
LogWrite "`n-------------Mechanical Drawing(s)------------"
foreach ($file in $MechDWGList)
{
    # Where the file name contains one of these filters
    foreach($filter in $MechDWGFilterList)
    {
        if($file.Name -like $filter)
        {
            $MechDWGFile += $file # this is where the error is happening, so I know it is probably something simple
            LogWrite $file.FullName
        }
    }
}
```

PowerShell 5.1 and Windows 10 OS is being used.

Could someone help me understand what's wrong with my syntax?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on the error message, `$MechDWGFile` already contains a single `[FileInfo]` object - the type of object returned by `Get-Item` or `Get-ChildItem`.

The `+=` operator is *overloaded* in PowerShell, meaning its behavior depends on the *type* of object you have on the left-hand side - in this case `$MechDWGFile` which contains a `[FileInfo]` object.

`$file` also contains such an object, but `[FileInfo] + [FileInfo]` doesn't make any sense, which is why you see the error.

To make the `+=` operator work, you need to create an array with the `@()` array subexpression operator:

```
$MechDWGFile = @()

# ...

# This now works
$MechDWGFile += $file
```

If you've initialized `$MechDWGFile` with output from `Get-Item` or `Get-ChildItem`, simply nest the existing pipeline in `@()`:

```
# `Get-ChildItem |Select -First 1` will only output 1 object, 
# but the @(...) makes PowerShell treat it as a 1-item array
# which in turn allows you to use `+=` later
$MechDWGFile = @(Get-ChildItem -Recurse -File |Select -First 1)
```

Comment: MathiasR.Jessen, understood. Thank you this makes sense! I tried initializing `$MechDWGFile` but without the `= @()`, just as `= $null` and `= 0`. Trying to grasp the `@` in PowerShell still, thought it was mostly meant for hash tables.

Answer (score 2):

One big caveat about arrays in PowerShell—they are ***immutable***.

Although you can "add" elements to an array in PowerShell using the overloaded `+=` operator, what it essentially does is creates a **new array** with the elements of the first operand and the second operand combined.

This may be more of a personal preference, but when I plan on looping over a bunch of items to populate an array, I use an `[ArrayList]` instead.  ArrayLists are mutable by design.  Why this isn't the default in PowerShell, I have no idea.

Adding a new element to an existing array:

```
$Array1 = Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\'
$Array2 = @()

# Add only the directories to our second array
foreach ($Item in $Array1) {
    if ($Item.PSIsContainer) {
        $Array2 += $Item    # This creates a new array every time
    }
}

$Array2
```

Adding a new element to an existing `[ArrayList]`:

```
$Array1 = Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\'
$Array2 = [System.Collections.ArrayList]@()

# Add only the directories to our ArrayList
foreach ($Item in $Array1) {
    if ($Item.PSIsContainer) {
        $null = $Array2.Add($Item)    # This does not create a new object each time.

        # The $null= prepend is because [ArrayList].Add() will output the ID of the
        #   last element added, so we assign that to null, keeping our console clean.
    }
}

$Array2
```

**Side note:** Like Mathias has stated, your variable `$MechDWGFile` may not have been initialized as an array, which is why the `+=` overload operator didn't work and instead threw an error.

Comment: DamianT. thank you for clarifying. It's a little confusing and eventually I'd like to learn more on the differences between arrays and arraylists, other than their immutability/mutability. One question, by using the overloaded `+=` operator which essentially creates a new array, does this mean that the active buffer has more consumed until the script ends/terminates? i.e. does the old array still exist when using the `+=' operator which now creates an additional array "in the buffer"?

Comment: The main difference is that when adding to an array, you are creating a new array object and then assigning the reference to your variable handle `$MechDWGFile`.  Each time you do that, the original object that was created is still in memory, but that memory is marked as free.  This means that you are making the system allocate and deallocate memory over and over.  It's inefficient.  When iterating many times over large amounts of data, adding to ArrayLists are more efficient because you're expanding the ArrayList itself instead of creating multiple arrays like `(a)`, `(a,b)`, `(a,b,c)`, etc.